# Will Google Cloud Messaging service run smoothly on completion of trial period of Google cloud platform

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

I am little confuse about the pricing of GCP and inclusion of GCM in it. Here are the queries about the same

1.Will the GCM will work smoothly even if we don't buy the google cloud platform when we switch to the production mode.

2.Are the google maps api are the part part of the GCP. Because I will be using them for the production. So I will have to buy the package for the google maps api.

Answer (score -1):

> Will the GCM will work smoothly even if we don't buy the google cloud platform

Yes. These products are not related at all.

> Are the google maps api are the part part of the GCP

No. Like GCM, it is a separate product.

Both GCM and the Google Maps API are free products, even in production.